# Building XFSTK error on Fedora 28 : /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options

Tags: fedora, compiling, make, cmake

I downloaded xfstk source and built it. I installed dependencies such as `boost`, `libusb-devel` etc... but although I installed `boost`, I getting error messages, such as the one below, reporting that `boost` is not installed.

```
...some output code here

[  0%] Built target docs
[  1%] Built target xfstk-command-line
[  2%] Automatic MOC for target XfstkFactory
[  2%] Built target XfstkFactory_autogen
[ 39%] Built target XfstkFactory
[ 40%] Automatic MOC for target xfstk-dldr-api
[ 40%] Built target xfstk-dldr-api_autogen
[ 40%] Linking CXX shared library libxfstk-dldr-api.so
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../libboost_program_options.so when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../libboost_program_options.a when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libboost_program_options.so when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libboost_program_options.a when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libboost_program_options.a when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../libboost_program_options.so when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/../../../libboost_program_options.a when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libboost_program_options.so when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //lib/libboost_program_options.a when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libboost_program_options.so when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible //usr/lib/libboost_program_options.a when searching for -lboost_program_options
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lboost_program_options
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [ancillary/configure/api/downloader-api/CMakeFiles/xfstk-dldr-api.dir/build.make:137: ancillary/configure/api/downloader-api/libxfstk-dldr-api.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:366: ancillary/configure/api/downloader-api/CMakeFiles/xfstk-dldr-api.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:152: all] Error 2
[frogwine@leopardpro build]$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You typically have 2 paths to take when you're trying to build software on Linux distros.

#### Options

1. Rely on the package manager of the Linux distro to do the heavy lifting for you
2. Incorporate your self compiled libraries into LD's path so that build/config tools are aware of it.

**Option 1**

For number 1, you can install `boost` using your distros package manager. I'm more familiar with Redhat distros, and for these you'd do this:

```
$ sudo yum search boost | grep ^boost | head
yum search boost | grep ^boost | head -10
boost-atomic.i686 : Run-Time component of boost atomic library
boost-atomic.x86_64 : Run-Time component of boost atomic library
boost-chrono.i686 : Run-Time component of boost chrono library
boost-chrono.x86_64 : Run-Time component of boost chrono library
boost-context.i686 : Run-Time component of boost context switching library
boost-context.x86_64 : Run-Time component of boost context switching library
boost-date-time.i686 : Run-Time component of boost date-time library
boost-date-time.x86_64 : Run-Time component of boost date-time library
boost-devel.i686 : The Boost C++ headers and shared development libraries
boost-devel.x86_64 : The Boost C++ headers and shared development libraries
```

And then install whatever you need from this output:

```
$ sudo yum install -y boost boost-devel ....
```

**Option 2**

For number 2, I've covered this already in this U&L Q&A titled: [Confusion about linking boost library while compilation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104087/7453).